# Error importing project with Eclipse: JavaCC

Tags: java, eclipse, m2eclipse

I am getting this error everytime I want to import some maven projects in Eclipse:

[image: Fancy error]

I already installed JavaCC plugin and CheckStyle for Eclipse, yet I can't pass this because if I finish by resolving later, many projects won't show or do not detect source folders.

Any Ideas?

Comment: try intellij. it comes with maven support by default

Comment: Yeah... I have been thinking of it but I just can't afford it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try installing the m2e javacc connector from https://github.com/objectledge/maven-extensions.

The connector is described at http://objectledge.org/confluence/display/TOOLS/javacc-maven-plugin+connector

The stable p2 update site is at : http://objectledge.github.com/maven-extensions/connectors/updates/milestones

Answer (score 0):

Could not install that plugin in Eclipse Neon ...

while the [javacc-maven-plugin](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/javacc-maven-plugin/2.6/javacc-maven-plugin-2.6.jar) also provides the dependencies.